# Let $ Y = \{ 1 + x, 1 − x + x^2 , 1 + 3 x − x^2 \} \subseteq P^2 ( \mathbb{R} ).$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Show that $Y$ does not span $P^2$ and find a basis for the span of $Y$.

I can row reduce the matrix so that the bottom row is all zeros is this enough to prove that it does not span? I find it easy to show that something does span but not to show that it does not span...

The basis I got was $\{ 1 + (1/2)x^2, x + (-1/2)x^2 \}$ is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your calculations are correct and the basis for the span of $Y$ is good.

It would have been very helpful if you had your matrix, and its row reduced form written down, so the reader has an easier time to see your complete proof.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

For this particular question, we are told that it doesn't span $P^2(\mathbb{R})$ but we have to prove it.

It is easy to see that the first two polynomials are not multiple of each other, I shall try to prove that the third is a linear combination of them. By observing the coefficient of $x^2$ and the constant term. I can quickly write down that

$$2(1+x)-(1-x+x^2) = (1+3x-x^2)$$

Hence a basis is $\{ 1+x, 1-x+x^2 \}$.

To check that  $\{ 1+ \frac12 x^2, x-\frac12 x^2 \}$ is a valid basis:

$$(1+ \frac12 x^2)+ (x-\frac12 x^2)=1+x$$

$$(1+ \frac12 x^2)-(x-\frac12 x^2)=1-x+x^2$$

Yup, it is correct.